# Cubemos Skeleton Tracking SDK in Unity wrapper, realsense2.dll not found, cubemos_engine.dll not found, RealSense pipeline not initialized! error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, realsense

I have recently purchased the *Cubemos Skeleton Tracking SDK*. After I installed it I tried to make a game with the Unity wrapper package.

When I played the HeloCubemosScene, I got the following errors:

1. **DllNotFoundException: realsense2** and **RealSense pipeline not initialized!** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jun9c.png)
2. **DllNotFoundException: cubemos_engine.dll** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grvEt.png)

I tried to fix the errors by following the troubleshooting steps written in the GettingStartedGuide.pdf, that can be downloaded from the [Cubemos site](https://www.cubemos.com/). But nothing solved the problems.

What can cause the problems and how could I solve them?

**My specs:**
CPU: Intel i9-9900X
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080Ti
RAM: 64 GB
Platform: Windows 10
Unity version: 2018.4.11f1
Cubemos version: 3.0

Comment: I have edited the question to a formal way and added the answer. Is it a proper form or should I change anything?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it looks helpful. My only suggestion is to include the stack trace with the error message directly in the post (instead of as an image), to make your post more readable & searchable. See related [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of issues with the *Cubemos skeleton tracking SDK* when I tried to use it in *Unity*.

The biggest problem that Cubemos never mentioned is that **the Unity wrapper only works on Intel CPUs that have integrated GPU in them**. It does not work on systems with AMD CPUs and configs that only have dedicated graphics cards.

My PC has an Intel i9-9900X which does not contain an integrated graphics card and an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080Ti.

The setup:

I installed the Cubemos Skeleton Tracking SDK 3.0 then the supported Unity 2018.4.11f1 version.
I created the project and imported the skeleton-tracking.unitypackage.
When I tried to run the *HeloCubemosScene* I got the following two errors:
***DllNotFoundException: realsense2*** and ***RealSense pipeline not initialized!***
[First Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghKMW.png)
I tried to solve the problems by copying the *realsense2.dll* into the *Cubemos.SkeletonTracking/Runtime/Plugins* folder.
The two errors disappeared but a new error appeared:
***DllNotFoundException: cubemos_engine.dll***
[Second Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3zK5.png)
I tried to do the same thing as before, so I copied the *cubemos_engine.dll* and pasted it into the *Plugins* folder. But this time it did not solve the problem.
I did every troubleshooting step that was written in the Cubemos *GettingStartedGuide.pdf*, but nothing really seemed to work.

At this time I tried to contact Cubemos about my issue with the Unity wrapper. After a week I got a response that said:
**The Unity wrapper has problems when there is a non-Intel GPU present. Do you have any chance to try on a system without Nvidia GPU? Otherwise, the wrapper will not work, unfortunately.**

Fortunately, I had a laptop (Dell G3 15) with an Intel CPU that has Intel UHD 630 integrated GPU in it (It also has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti dedicated graphics card, but it did not matter).
I installed the Cubemos Skeleton Tracking SDK 3.0 and the Unity 2018.4.11f1 version. Then I created a project and imported the skeleton-tracking.unitypackage. And this time when I clicked on Play in the Unity Editor it was working fine!!
[Working Unity Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF5fd.png)

I hope I could help some people with this post!